# Encoding special characters to Base64 in Javascript and decoding using base64_decode() in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

My problem is that the base64_decode() function does not work with special characters. Maybe the problem is that I am using an ajax event and I am parsing the data using base64.encode from javascript.
js code:

```
description: $.base64.encode($("#Contact_description").val())
```

and this is the php code:

```
$model->description = base64_decode($model->description);
```

where `$model->description` is the `$("#Contact_description").val()` value

Example this is the description value : **Traian Băsescu** and this is how I look after using the decode from php : **Traian A�sescu**. What should I do ?

**UPDATE:** 
This the header information from firebug:

```
Content-Length  143
Content-Type    text/html; **charset=UTF-8**
Date    Fri, 20 Mar 2015 12:37:01 GMT
```

Comment: Check your charset format and change to UTF-8 w/o BOM.

Comment: ok but how can I do that ? :D

Comment: did you try with utf8_encode($data)

Comment: utf8_encode() is from PHP , I am using javascript to encode

Comment: Save your php file with charset codification with **UTF-8 w/o BOM**. If you're using Notepad++ you will see _Format_ option at the top. You can set charset from there and save

Comment: It is already utf-8, I don't believe it is the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works for me:

JavaScript:

```
// Traian Băsescu encodes to VHJhaWFuIELEg3Nlc2N1
var base64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( $("#Contact_description").val() )));
```

PHP:

```
$utf8 = base64_decode($base64);
```

Comment: Since `unescape` is deprecated, you really should read this and follow all the links to further information and alternative implementations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa#Unicode_Strings

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that Javascript strings are encoded in UTF-16, and browsers do not offer very many good tools to deal with encodings. A great resource specifically for dealing with Base64 encodings and Unicode can be found at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Their suggested solution for encoding strings **without using the often cited solution involving the deprecated `unescape` function** is:

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}
```

For further solutions and details I highly recommend you read the entire page.

Comment: this works and is not deprecated!