# How to support special characters react natvie base 64

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64, decode, encode

How can we support special characters in react native base 64?

```
import base from 'react-native-base64'

....
base.encode(str)
....
```

str would be **asdĞ** or any other special characters from some languages.

I have used this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-base64

Currently while decoding it converting the string to **asd**

---

Here is the example code

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import base from "react-native-base64";

const Decode = () => {
  const string = "asdĞ";
  const encode = base.encode(string);
  const decode = base.decode(encode);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{"String = " + string}</Text>
      <Text>{"DecodeS = " + decode}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Decode;
```

you can try it on
https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-currying-te3ki4?file=/src/Decode.js

Comment: This is usually a problem with the chosen character encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, etc.) but not a Base64 problem. Base64 doesn't 'know' anything about the contents and a  Base64 encoder/decoder just encodes bytes to a Base64 string and decodes a Bases64 string to bytes and the bytes will be the same after decoding. Please add a [mre] so that we can see what you actually do and where the problem might be.

Comment: @jps I have added link for example code https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-currying-te3ki4?file=/src/Decode.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before you encode to Base64 and the counterpart `decodeURIComponent` after decoding from Base64

> The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

This solution was proposed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) and I found that page by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29167148/7329832) (this answer did not directly answer the above question and the proposed solution in it did not work for me). It's recommended to read the whole linked page to understand the problem and the possible solutions.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import base from "react-native-base64";

function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
  return base.encode(encodeURIComponent(str));
}

function UnicodeDecodeB64(str) {
  return decodeURIComponent(base.decode(str));
}

const Decode = () => {
  const string = "asdĞ";
  //const encode = base.encode(string);
  const encode = b64EncodeUnicode(string);
  const decode = UnicodeDecodeB64(encode);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{"String = " + string}</Text>
      <Text>{"DecodeS = " + decode}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Decode;
```

The output is

> Decode Example
> String = asdĞ
> DecodeS = asdĞ

In the code above you can also use the standard `atob`/`btoa` instead of `base.decode`/`base.encode`

Comment: @jps Here I have to use unescape `base.encode(unescape(encodeURIComponent('')));` but it's deperecated any alternative way to use?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74276401/what-are-alterative-of-unescape-as-its-deperecated